# How can I make sure the user only inputs 'y' or 'n' in the program?

Tags: python

How can I make sure the user input only 'y' or 'n' in and make the program only accept 'y' or'n' as an answer?

```
while True:
        try:
            cont = input("Do you want to continue? If so enter 'y'.")
            if cont != "n" or cont !="y":
                print("Please enter 'y' or 'n'")
            else:
                break
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter 'y' or 'n'")
    else:
            break
```

Comment: Because you are mixing up 'and' and 'or'

Comment: Is that meant to be a `try ... except ... else` block or a `while ... else` block? The indenting is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `and` operator instead of `or` operator. To avoid such confusion, you can try and write such conditions in close to english way, like this

```
cont="a"
if cont not in ("n", "y"):
    print "Welcome"
```

This can be read as "if cont is not one of...". The advantage of this method is that, you can check for n number of elements in a single condition. For example,

```
if cont not in ("n", "y", "N", "Y"):
```

this will be `True` only when `cont` is case-insensitively `n` or `y`

**Edit:** As suggested by Eric in the comments, for single character checking we can do something like this

```
if cont not in "nyNY":
```

Comment: `is` should _not_ be used for string equality

Comment: @Eric I got what you were saying. I removed that from my answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Note that for single-character `cont`, this can be abbreviated `cont not in "nNyY"`

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr `is` will check if both the references are the same.

Comment: But python strings are immutable. If `x="s"` then `id(x) == id("s")`. When assigned the value `"s"`, for all intents `x` *becomes* `"s"`. Hence my confusion.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr: That's not how string interning works. `''.join(["a", "b"]) is "ab"` gives `False` in my interpreter.

Comment: @Eric Not disputing, I just checked and it does the same on mine too :( I'm just curious to know *why*?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr: remember, `x is y` implied `id(x) == id(y)`, and in CPython, `id(x)` is the memory address of `x`. Just because two variables contain the same immutable value does not mean they refer to the same piece of memory.

Comment: @Eric Hmmm... ok, I didn't know that. Thanks :) And by "thanks :)" I mean "Thanks, now I have a bunch of code I should rewrite :("

Answer (score 4):

A condition of the type `if cont != "n" or cont !="y":` will always be true as `cont` can not be `n` and `y` at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Because it should be `if cont != "n" and cont !="y":`. Every word is either not `n` or not `y`.

Comment: Case sensitive, indicate emphasis another way.

Comment: @agf Right, it's still early in the morning. :)